# Bash prompt string appears in same line as curl command output

Tags: bash, prompt

When I run a curl command, the json response that it returns collides with the bash prompt string:

```
~$curl localhost:8001/api
{"message":"this is a test message"}~$
```

Notice `~$` at the end of second line. 
I have customized my bash prompt string to contain the working folder:

```
PS1=\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\W\$
```

It appears the local server (nodejs) hasn't added a newline character at the end.

How can I ensure that my bash prompt string always comes at a newline?

Comment: Why dont you just add `echo ""`after `curl`: `curl localhost:8001/api;echo ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simple answer: use the `\n` (newline) special character at the beginning of your prompt string. It will ensure the bash prompt string **always** comes at a newline. This might however happen more often than you'd want.
2. If you only run into this when using `curl`, have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14614203)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to do this for `curl` commands and don't want an extra newline added to your prompt, just echo the output:

```
~$ echo "$(curl localhost:8001/api)"
{"message":"this is a test message"}
~$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force a newline after every command in the bash shell with the [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html).

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo"
```

Now, after every command or before every prompt `echo` is called without argument. Then `echo` only prints a newline. Notice, that if you run a command that ends with a newline, you will now have 2 newlines at the end. See:

```
echo -n foo
foo$ 
$ PROMPT_COMMAND="echo"
echo -n foo
foo
$ echo foo
foo

$
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to append a newline manually is `&& echo`:

```
~$ curl localhost:8001/api && echo
{"message":"this is a test message"}
~$
```